# select2.js check if has at least one option selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to check if select2.js has at least one option selected?

The code bellow shows the message 'Please select at least one item in the list.' even after selecting one item.

```
$('form.validate-form').validator({
    disable: false
});

$( "select.validate" ).each(function() {
    $(this).validator();
    $(this).get(0).setCustomValidity('Please select at least one item in the list.');
});
```

How can I make the message 'Please select at least one item in the list.' disappear after selecting at least one option?

I am using Bootstrap validator plugin.

**[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/jEADR/1720/)**

Comment: are you using  jquery validation

Comment: No, I am using Bootstrap validator plugin.